# $E(X)E(1/X) \leq (a + b)^2 / 4ab$

Tags: expected-value, probability-inequalities

I've worked on the following problem and have a solution (included below), but I would like to know if there are any *other* solutions to this problem, especially more elegant solutions that apply well known inequalities.

**QUESTION**: Suppose we have a random variable s.t. $P(a<X<b) =1$  where 0 < a < X < b , a and b both positive constants.

Show that $E(X)E(\frac{1}{X}) \le \frac{(a+b)^2}{4ab}$

*Hint*:  find constant c and d s.t. $\frac{1}{x} \le cx+d$ when $a<x<b$, and argue that then we shall have $E(\frac{1}{X}) \le cE(X)+d$

**MY SOLUTION**: For a line $cx+d$ that cuts through $\frac{1}{X}$ at the points x=a and x = b, it's easy to show that $ c = - \frac{1}{ab} $  and $d = \frac{a+b}{ab} $,

So, $ \frac{1}{X} \le - \frac{1}{ab} X + \frac{a+b}{ab} $, and therefore:

$$ E(\frac{1}{X}) \le - \frac{1}{ab} E(X) + \frac{a+b}{ab} $$

$$ abE(\frac{1}{X}) + E(X) \le (a+b) $$

Now, because both sides of the inequality are positive, it follows that:

$$ [abE(\frac{1}{X}) + E(X)]^2 \le (a+b)^2 $$

$$ (ab)^2E(\frac{1}{X})^2 + 2abE(\frac{1}{X})E(X) + E(X)^2  \le (a+b)^2 $$

Then, for the LHS, we can see that 
$2abE(\frac{1}{X})E(X) \le (ab)^2E(\frac{1}{X})^2 + E(X)^2$

because

$0 \le (ab)^2E(\frac{1}{X})^2 - 2abE(\frac{1}{X})*E(X) + E(X)^2 = [abE(\frac{1}{X}) - E(X)]^2 $

SO,
$$ 4abE(\frac{1}{X})E(X) \le (ab)^2E(\frac{1}{X})^2 + 2abE(\frac{1}{X})E(X) + E(X)^2  \le (a+b)^2 $$

and therefore:

$$ E(\frac{1}{X})E(X) \le \frac{(a+b)^2}{4ab} $$  Q.E.D.

Thanks for any *additional* solutions you might be able to provide.  Cheers!

Comment: Did you try applying the hint? What happened?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest *drawing a picture*, and marking in a and b. A linear function with the property indicated in the hint should be obvious.

Comment: @Glen_b:  Yes, I did try the hint, but as you can see above, the hint does not provide an obvious solution to the inequality (at least to one that I can readily see).

Comment: Even though it's not something you might get credit for, as routine bookwork it still falls under `self-study` and follows the same rules.

Comment: ah-HA!  I think I solved it!  Sorry for posting the "Self-Study" question where it didn't belong, but is it allowed if I found a solution and would like verification that the aforementioned solution is valid?  

Also, If I have solved the problem, am I allowed to ask if their are other solutions out there (to help me better understand the problem)?

Sorry if I'm asking a lot of rookie questions, but I am relatively wet behind the ears with stats.stackexchange.  Thanks a lot for your guidance  :)

Comment: It's perfectly allowed to post self-study questions here if they follow the [guidelines](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for asking them (that is, 'they belong' if you do it right - read the 'on hold' text above carefully). I believe with your edits your post does follow the guidelines now (or comes close enough) and I nominated your post to reopen about half an hour ago; it will take more votes than mine though. If you want to ask if the answer is right, post it in your Q., and ask there. You can ask for other solutions, but keep in mind the guidelines on *answering*.

Comment: Given your answer looks like quite a solid solution that actually uses the hint in what I believe is the intended fashion, I think you could post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know it's stated in the problem, but I figured I'd put it in the answer bank:

For some line $cx+d$ that cuts through $\frac{1}{X}$ at the points x=a and x = b, it's easy to show that $ c = - \frac{1}{ab} $  and $d = \frac{a+b}{ab} $,

So, $ \frac{1}{X} \le - \frac{1}{ab} X + \frac{a+b}{ab} $, and therefore:

$$ E(\frac{1}{X}) \le - \frac{1}{ab} E(X) + \frac{a+b}{ab} $$

$$ abE(\frac{1}{X}) + E(X) \le (a+b) $$

Now, because both sides of the inequality are positive, it follows that:

$$ [abE(\frac{1}{X}) + E(X)]^2 \le (a+b)^2 $$

$$ (ab)^2E(\frac{1}{X})^2 + 2abE(\frac{1}{X})E(X) + E(X)^2  \le (a+b)^2 $$

Then, for the LHS, we can see that 
$2abE(\frac{1}{X})E(X) \le (ab)^2E(\frac{1}{X})^2 + E(X)^2$

because

$0 \le (ab)^2E(\frac{1}{X})^2 - 2abE(\frac{1}{X})*E(X) + E(X)^2 = [abE(\frac{1}{X}) - E(X)]^2 $

SO,
$$ 4abE(\frac{1}{X})E(X) \le (ab)^2E(\frac{1}{X})^2 + 2abE(\frac{1}{X})E(X) + E(X)^2  \le (a+b)^2 $$

and therefore:

$$ E(\frac{1}{X})E(X) \le \frac{(a+b)^2}{4ab} $$

Comment: It's of interest that the RHS is the square of the ratio of the arithmetic mean to the geometric mean of the endpoints $(\text{AM}(a,b)/\text{GM}(a,b))^2$. While this upper bound comes from a secant of the $1/x$ function, it's also interesting to investigate the lower bound gained by drawing a tangent at the midpoint.

Answer (score 5):

Once we observe that both sides of the inequality are scale invariant, it follows immediately by combining two simple, well-known inequalities, of which the most notable is that *correlation coefficients cannot be less than $\newcommand{\e}{\mathbb{E}}-1$.*

---

The [Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) guarantees that the correlation coefficient $\rho(X,Y)$ of any two random variables $X$ and $Y$ lies between $-1$ and $1$.  Using the definition of correlation and focusing on the lower bound of $-1$ allows us to express this inequality in the form

$$-\text{sd}(X)\text{sd}(Y) \le \rho(X,Y)\text{sd}(X)\text{sd}(Y) = \text{Cov}(X,Y) = \e[XY] - \e[X]\e[Y].$$

If we let $Y=1/X$, the product $\e[X]\e[1/X]$ is recognizable right there at the very end (which of course is what inspired this approach).

Using the simplification $\e[XY]=\e[X/X]=\e[1]=1$, isolate the last term algebraically to obtain

$$\e[X]\e[1/X] \le 1 + \text{sd}(X)\text{sd}(1/X).$$

When a variable's values are confined to an interval $[a,b]$, its variance is limited by the value $(b-a)^2/4$.  This is proven in several elegant, elementary, and informative ways at [Variance of a bounded random variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45588); it comes down to the fact that variances cannot be negative. Consequently

$$\text{sd}(X)\text{sd}(1/X) \le (b-a)^2/4.$$

We may freely rescale $X$ because the left side of this inequality does not thereby change.  Select a scale in which $ab=1$ (which is possible because both $a$ and $b$ are positive).  This allows us to rewrite the preceding in a form where the right hand side is obviously scale invariant, too:

$$\text{sd}(X)\text{sd}(1/X) \le \frac{(b-a)^2}{4} = \frac{1}{ab}\frac{(b-a)^2}{4}=\frac{(b-a)^2}{4ab}.$$

These two inequalities finish the job:

$$\e[X]\e[1/X] \le 1 + \text{sd}(X)\text{sd}(1/X) \le 1 + \frac{(b-a)^2}{4ab} = \frac{(a+b)^2}{4ab}.$$